# Getting html and js weather api request to work in node. It works before I upload to Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

It works fine outside of node. I cant get it to work in node.js. Please help as this is my last resort. Ill need to see i suppose the correct layout of app.js
ITs something simple i knwo. No answers out there currently. I hope stack can 
help.
Thanks. Mike

html file:

Weather

## Get Weather Conditions From Anywhere!

Enter a location:
          
          Get Current Humidity!

```
JS FILE:

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#weatherLocation').click(function() {
    let city = $('#location').val();
    $('#location').val("");
    $.ajax({
      url: `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=b7a0ab9fa0acf51a850b7a621c63d38f`,
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        format: 'json'
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $('.showHumidity').text(`The humidity in ${city} is ${response.main.humidity}%`);
        $('.showTemp').text(`The temperature in Kelvins is ${response.main.temp}.`);
      },
      error: function() {
        $('#errors').text("There was an error processing your request. Please try again.");
      }
    });
  });
});

APP.JS FILE
// app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');

app.use(express.static("app")); // Allow access to content of views folder (Showing how we get app to recognise folders)
 // Allow access to content of views folder (Showing how we get app to recognise folders)
 // Allow access to content of views folder (Showing how we get app to recognise folders)
app.use(express.static("js"));
app.use(express.static("views")); // Allow access to content of views folder (Showing how we get app to recognise folders)
app.use(express.static("images")); // Allow access to images folder (Showing how we get app to recognise folders)
 // Allow access to content of views folder (Showing how we get app to recognise folders)
 // Allow access to scripts folder {No need for this)
app.use(express.static("css")); // Allow access to css folder (Showing how we get app to recognise folders)
 // Allow access to js folder (Showing how we get app to recognise 




var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Your app listening at https://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js doesn't support HTML, or any kind of DOM*. Use `console.log` calls to output to `stdout` instead.

---

*by default.

Comment: Sorry could you explain more code wise-  standard input and output please, I need to add code to the app.js file right.Please demonstrate. I forgot to upload html  :(. Im calling the function through that and works pre node upload....

Comment: @COMMSFORYOU Node.js isn't a web browser. It doesn't support HTML, so the HTML functions won't work in it. This includes the `$('#foo').text()` calls. If you replace those with `console.log()` calls, your code will work properly.